# unable to find intended htmlcollection item

Tags: javascript, htmlcollection

I have following `console.log` statements inside the `onTemplateAdvancedSelect` function:

```
const onTemplateAdvancedSelect = (e) => {
    let inputFileType = document.querySelector('input[type=file]')
       inputFileType.classList.add("toDisableOnSelect");
       inputFileType.disabled = true;

      let htmlCollection = document.getElementsByClassName('p-button p-component p-button-icon-only')
       console.log("Printing htmlCollection");
       console.log(htmlCollection.length);
       console.log(htmlCollection);
       console.log(htmlCollection.item(20));
       
}
```

**Observations:**

1. `console.log(htmlCollection.length);` prints 34
2. `console.log(htmlCollection);` prints the following:

   ```
     HTMLCollection {
    0: button.p - button.p - component.datareq - ew - edit.p - button - icon - only,
    1: button.p - button.p - component.datareq - ew - edit.p - button - icon - only,
    2: button.p - button.p - component.datareq - ew - edit.p - button - icon - only,
    3: button.p - button.p - component.datareq - ew - edit.p - button - icon - only,
    4: button.p - button.p - component.datareq - ew - edit.p - button - icon - only,
    5: button.p - button.p - component.datareq - ew - edit.p - button - icon - only,
    6: button.p - button.p - component.datareq - ew - edit.p - button - icon - only,
    7: button.p - button.p - component.datareq - ew - edit.p - button - icon - only,
    8: button.p - button.p - component.datareq - ew - edit.p - button - icon - only,
    9: button.p - button.p - component.datareq - ew - edit.p - button - icon - only,
    …
   }​
   0: < button class = "p-button p-component dat…edit p-button-icon-only"
   type = "button"
   style = "margin-right: 5px; color: black;" > ​
    1: < button class = "p-button p-component dat…edit p-button-icon-only"
    type = "button"
    style = "margin-right: 5px; color: black;" > ​
    2: < button class = "p-button p-component dat…edit p-button-icon-only"
    type = "button"
    style = "margin-right: 5px; color: black;" > ​
    3: < button class = "p-button p-component dat…edit p-button-icon-only"
    type = "button"
    style = "margin-right: 5px; color: black;" > ​
    4: < button class = "p-button p-component dat…edit p-button-icon-only"
    type = "button"
    style = "margin-right: 5px; color: black;" > ​
    5: < button class = "p-button p-component dat…edit p-button-icon-only"
    type = "button"
    style = "margin-right: 5px; color: black;" > ​
    6: < button class = "p-button p-component dat…edit p-button-icon-only"
    type = "button"
    style = "margin-right: 5px; color: black;" > ​
    7: < button class = "p-button p-component dat…edit p-button-icon-only"
    type = "button"
    style = "margin-right: 5px; color: black;" > ​
    8: < button class = "p-button p-component dat…edit p-button-icon-only"
    type = "button"
    style = "margin-right: 5px; color: black;" > ​
    9: < button class = "p-button p-component dat…edit p-button-icon-only"
    type = "button"
    style = "margin-right: 5px; color: black;" > ​
    10: < button class = "p-button p-component dat…edit p-button-icon-only"
    type = "button"
    style = "margin-right: 5px; color: black;" > ​
    11: < button class = "p-button p-component dat…edit p-button-icon-only"
    type = "button"
    style = "margin-right: 5px; color: black;" > ​
    12: < button class = "p-button p-component dat…edit p-button-icon-only"
    type = "button"
   style = "margin-right: 5px; color: black;" > ​
    13: < button class = "p-button p-component dat…edit p-button-icon-only"
    type = "button"
    style = "margin-right: 5px; color: black;" > ​
    14: < button class = "p-button p-component dat…edit p-button-icon-only"
    type = "button"
    style = "margin-right: 5px; color: black;" > ​
    15: < button class = "p-button p-component dat…edit p-button-icon-only"
    type = "button"
    style = "margin-right: 5px; color: black;" > ​
    16: < button class = "p-button p-component dat…edit p-button-icon-only"
    type = "button"
    style = "margin-right: 5px; color: black;" > ​
    17: < button class = "p-button p-component dat…edit p-button-icon-only"
    type = "button"
    style = "margin-right: 5px; color: black;" > ​
    18: < button class = "p-button p-component dat…edit p-button-icon-only"
    type = "button"
    style = "margin-right: 5px; color: black;" > ​
    19: < button class = "p-button p-component dat…edit p-button-icon-only"
    type = "button"
   style = "margin-right: 5px; color: black;" > ​
    20: < button class = "p-button p-component p-button-icon-only"
    type = "button" > ​
    21: < button class = "p-button p-component p-button-icon-only"
    type = "button"
    style = "margin-right: 5px;" > ​
    22: < button class = "p-button p-component p-button-icon-only"
    type = "button" > ​
    23: < button class = "p-button p-component p-button-icon-only"
    type = "button"
    style = "margin-right: 5px;" > ​
    24: < button class = "p-button p-component p-button-icon-only"
    type = "button" > ​
    25: < button class = "p-button p-component p-button-icon-only"
    type = "button"
    style = "margin-right: 5px;" > ​
    26: < button class = "p-button p-component p-button-icon-only"
    type = "button" > ​
    27: < button class = "p-button p-component p-button-icon-only"
    type = "button"
    style = "margin-right: 5px;" > ​
    28: < button class = "p-button p-component p-button-icon-only"
    type = "button" > ​
    29: < button class = "p-button p-component p-button-icon-only"
    type = "button"
    style = "margin-right: 5px;" > ​
    30: < button class = "p-button p-component p-button-icon-only"
    type = "button" > ​
    31: < button class = "p-button p-component p-button-icon-only"
    type = "button"
    style = "margin-right: 5px;" > ​
    32: < button class = "p-button p-component p-button-icon-only"
    type = "button" > ​
    33: < button class = "p-button p-component p-button-icon-only"
    type = "button"
    style = "margin-right:     5px;" > ​
    34: < button class = "p-button p-component p-button-icon-only"
    type = "button" > ​
    length: 35​ <
    prototype >: HTMLCollectionPrototype {
        item: item(),
        namedItem: namedItem(),
        length: Getter,
        …
    }
    DataRequestForm.js: 689: 13
   ```
3. `console.log(htmlCollection.item(20));` prints the following:

`<button class="p-button p-component p-button-icon-only" type="button" style="margin-right: 5px;">`

However, I am looking for this one `20: <button class="p-button p-component p-button-icon-only" type="button">`. How can I get this one ? My end goal is to add an event listner and as soon as user clicks on this button
I want to set  `inputFileType.disabled = false;`.

Comment: so look over the collection and add event listeners? I am not sure what you are asking

Comment: First I want to grab this item `20: <button class="p-button p-component p-button-icon-only" type="button">` and then attach an event listener to this button to set `inputFileType.disabled = false;`.

Comment: htmlCollection[20].addEventListener(......)

Comment: thanks but I am wondering when I am trying to print the `20th` element like this  `console.log(htmlCollection.item(20)`, why it is printing something else `<button class="p-button p-component p-button-icon-only" type="button" style="margin-right: 5px;">` and not the correct one ` <button class="p-button p-component p-button-icon-only" type="button">`

Comment: tested it using `htmlCollection[20].addEventListener("click", function(){inputFileType.disabled = false;});` but it didn't work. Perhaps it's not picking up the correct `20th` element and hence it's not working?

Comment: The htmlCollection list is index based meaning that the 20th item in the list has index 19, so try `htmlCollection.item(20-1)`

Comment: But there  must be something that distinguishes these buttens -- clearly selecting for classname does not. Do the buttons have a name, id or something else?

Comment: getElementsByClassName is a live html collection. So it updates as elements are rendered.

Comment: htmlCollection.item(19) prints the following `<button class="p-button p-component dat…edit p-button-icon-only" type="button" style="margin-right: 5px; color: black;">`, which is not what I am looking for.

Comment: @epascarello but printing the elements in the previous line seams to work...

Comment: It's from a react example where I have this function in the code below: https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-chandrasekhar-qz9tg?file=/src/demo/FileUploadDemo.js

However, since above example has only one htmlcollection, I am getting the correct one when I select a file using `Choose` button. In my code, I have 34 different HTML collections as shown in my original post.